# jquery unwrap a ul nested inside another with the same id

Tags: jquery

hello this is what my html looks like (I didn't make any mistakes one ul is nested inside the next and they both have the same id)

```
<ul id="members-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <ul id="members-list">
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to use `jquery().unwrap();` to remove the second ul and the closing tag. but leave all the li elements

Comment: They shouldn't both have the same id, though.

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: well 2 sites are clones and i want to display some information on the next site. can you help with the question on hand? I am not sure why you are sayin "shouldnt " if you know how please help if you don't no need to tell me they shouldnt be the same I already know that but in this case thats the problem ... they ARE

Comment: try `$('ul[id="members-list"] ul[id="members-list"] li').unwrap();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made two mistakes

1. There can not be more then one element having same ID.
2. UL can not be immediate child of another UL.

But if you really want to remove nested UL try following line.

```
$("#members-list ul li").unwrap()
```

Look at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/2ajqT/2/)

Comment: I want to use unwrap to do it to leave the li elements inside the ul

Comment: @fogsy please check now